# How to display input type value as encrypted? Can it be achieved using angular js?

Tags: html, css

I have a website where the users should be able to scan an RFID card in a text field through RFID reader in order to validate the card. The thing is, I don’t want them to be able to see the input. They should see ******** instead of the actual number.

Is that possible without using password field, because the password field brings some other problems like constantly asking for updating the password for the website and having some ***** by default.

without using :

```
input { -webkit-text-security: none; }
input { -webkit-text-security: circle; }
input { -webkit-text-security: square; }
input { -webkit-text-security: disc; /* Default */ }
```

The two fields Name and value after submit should be shown as below :

Name : test
value : ***

Comment: See [<input type="password">](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/password)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way by using pure CSS and HTML and avoiding `type="password"`. The only way I could think of to make it at least remotly secure is using the `filter: blur();` property.

```css
body {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.input-container {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 2px rgba(33, 150, 243, 0.5);
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.input-container:focus-within {
  border-color: #2196f3;
}

input {
  height: 36px;
  font-size: inherit;
  line-height: 1;
  border: 0;
  filter: blur(4px);
}
```

```html
<div class="input-container">
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make your type password and autocomplete off

```html
<div class="input-container">
  <input type="password" autocomplete="off">
</div>
```